# How to trick autocomplete in Python for functions returning objects with dynamic attributes

Tags: python, eclipse, dynamic, autocomplete, pycharm

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 5
        self.c = 0

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.e = 10
        self.d = 11

def jojo(li):
    return li[1]

def lala():
    a = [A(), B()]
    b = jojo(a)
    return b

lala()
```

How can I make PyCharm's (or any IDE's) autocomplete functionality to suggest me b, c, d and e as attributes for lala().
can i define a custom list somewhere?

Comment: isinstance doesnt work

Comment: isinstance does not work, since *b* (element index 1) is an instance of *B*, not *A*. Since lala is not a multiple inheriting class, but just has a list of data with instances, I find the demand for a successful autocomplete somewhat ambitious. For which language/IDE combination did you succeed?

Comment: I don't succeed. 
Looking for Python in PyCharm or Eclipse.
Above code of course is a simplified explanation of the problem I'm facing, I removed the isinstance, since it's not working anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution for Python 3**

You can just use [Union type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) if it's possible to list all possibilities.

I have added `C` class because it's not in `A` and `B` class hierarchy so the example will be more clear and holistic.

```
from typing import Union


class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 5
        self.c = 0

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.e = 10
        self.d = 11

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.f = 12

def jojo(li):
    return li[1]

def lala() -> Union[A, B, C]:
    a = [A(), B(), C()]
    b = jojo(a)
    return b

lala()
```

[image]

Comment: ah dang it, using Python 2.7 :-) any other suggestion?

Comment: some research brought me to https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code
Thx for the suggestion

Comment: its not working entirely as i wanted but it s already halfway there. I'll file my answer as a separate answer and select your guidance as the correct one

Answer (score 0):

For PYTHON 2

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 5
        self.c = 0

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.e = 10
        self.d = 11

def jojo(li):
    return li[1]

def lala():
    # type: () -> B
    a = [A(), B()]
    b = jojo(a)
    return b

lala()
```

Union doesn't work so only 1 class can be passed